# Display of the top 3 customers by number of orders

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find out the top 3 customers from a list.
I want to do this based on the number of orders.

At the end I would like to be able to display the following values:

| Client | Amount of Orders | Summed Amount of Ordervalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 1.400€ |
| D | 3 | 1.200€ |
| C | 2 | 400 € |

My output table is like the following just with way more clients

| Client | Order type | Amount per Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Container | 300 € |
| A | Container | 300 € |
| C | Trucking | 200 € |
| B | Storage | 100 € |
| A | Trucking | 400 € |
| A | Trucking | 400 € |
| D | Container | 600 € |
| C | Trucking | 200 € |
| D | Container | 300 € |
| D | Container | 300 € |

Comment: Your input table and output table information do not match. Edit your post to make it clear? How you get 512 for Top1>

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I made it a bit clearer what I want to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use below formula.

```
=QUERY(A1:C,"select A, count(A), sum(C) 
where A is not null 
group by A 
order by count(A) DESC 
limit 3")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try following query

```
Select Client,Count(Client) 'Amount of Orders',Sum(Amount) 'Summed Amount of 
Ordervalue' From OrderDetails Group By Client
```

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
Select Client,Count(Client) 'Amount of Orders',Sum(Amount) 'Summed Amount of 
Ordervalue' From OrderDetails Group By Client
```